# I'm trying to pass a state on ReactJs to a child component but the value isn't read

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous

here's the problem that I'm passing right now. I'm new on ReactJS, so it's very possible that I'm doing some rookie mistake. Right now I'm trying to update a child component with am update that I do through a click on another sibling component. The thing is that even though the click method do it's work the way it should do, when it comes to pass it's value to the child Component, it just doesn't work. Here goes the 2 components that I mentioned:

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchField from '../components/SearchField';
import ResultSearch from '../components/ResultSearch';

const fullURL = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';

export default class People extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    searchText: '',
    query: '',
    people: [],
    next: '',
    previous: ''
  };

  this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
  this.handleClickSearch = this.handleClickSearch.bind(this);
}

handleSearchChange(searchText){
  this.setState({
  searchText: searchText,
  });
}

handleClickSearch(query){
  this.setState({
  query: query,
  });

fetch(query)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({ next: responseJson.next })
    this.setState({ previous: responseJson.previous })
    this.setState({ people: responseJson.results.map(obj => obj) });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
}

render() {

return (
  <div>

    <SearchField inputSearch={this.state.searchText} fullURL={fullURL} onInputSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange} onClickSearch={this.handleClickSearch}/>
    { console.log(this.state) }
    <ResultSearch result={this.state.people} />

    </div>
   );
  }
 }
```

And here's the part of the Child Component that isn't working the way I thought it would:

```
import React from 'react';
import github from '../assets/images/home/social-github-pic.png';

export default class ResultSearch extends React.Component {

render() {
  console.log(this.props.result);
  if(this.props.result > 0) {
  return (
    <div className="container">

      <div className="ui five column grid container">

        <div className="column">
          <figure>
            <img className="socialIcons ui image" src={github} alt=""/>
            <figcaption>Character Name</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>

     ...
```

Comment: Does the `console.log(this.props.result);` print anything in your `ResultSearch` component? Is the fetch successful? You can also use React devtools browser extension to inspect the state and props of both these components to try and narrow down where it is going wrong.

Comment: Is `responseJson.results` an array? If so, you need to change your `if` statement to `this.props.result.length`. Also, you should also handle the case where there are no people in the array (rendering a `loading` sign of something like that)

Comment: @BravoZulu it was this way a few tries before, but trying it now, I noticed that I was writing lenght instead of length. Thanks for your help, bro.